# No puedo obtner y mandar el id de los datos de un combobox en JAVA patron MVC a SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mvc

ESTE ES MI JSP "INSERTAR":

```
<%  
    ProfesionalBE profesional = new ProfesionalBE();
    profesional.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombre"));
    profesional.setApellido(request.getParameter("apellido")); 
    profesional.setCorreo(request.getParameter("correo"));
    profesional.setId_nacionalidad(request.getParameter("idnacionalidad"));
    int b = new ProfesionalBR().RegistrarProfesional(profesional)    
%>
```

ESTE ES MI CLASE DAO el cual llama al insertar:

```
 public int InsertarProfesional(ProfesionalBE e){
        int  r =0;
         Connection con = new Conexion().conectarSQL();
         String sql = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Profesional (Nombre_profesional, Apellidos_profesional, Correo_profesional, id_Nacionalidad)  "
                 + "VALUES ('"+e.getNombre()+"','"+e.getApellido()+"','"+e.getCorreo()+"','"+e.getId_nacionalidad()+"')";

         try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
            st=null;     
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProfesionalDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         con=null;
   return r;
}
```

Mi problema es que al momento de insertar a la BD ya creada no me inserta nada, porque no lee el id como numero, mi consulta es como obtener el id de un combobox con datos mostrados de una tabla sql para poder registrarlos en otra tabla,

Comment: Has pensado en usar PreparedStatement para tu insert?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar PreparedStatement para definir el tipo de datos que mandarás a tu consulta:

```
<%  
    ProfesionalBE profesional = new ProfesionalBE();
    profesional.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombre"));
    profesional.setApellido(request.getParameter("apellido")); 
    profesional.setCorreo(request.getParameter("correo"));
    profesional.setId_nacionalidad(request.getParameter("idnacionalidad"));
    int b = new ProfesionalBR().RegistrarProfesional(profesional)    
%>

public int InsertarProfesional(ProfesionalBE e){
        int  r =0;
         Connection con = new Conexion().conectarSQL();
         String sql = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Profesional (Nombre_profesional, Apellidos_profesional, Correo_profesional, id_Nacionalidad) 
         values (?,?,?,?)";

         PreparedStatement statement=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
         statement.setString(1,e.getNombre());
         statement.setString(2,e.getApellido());
         statement.setString(3,e.getCorreo());
         statement.setInt(4,e.getId_nacionalidad());
         statement.executeUpdate();

         try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
            st=null;     
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProfesionalDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         con=null;
   return r;
}
```

Espero y te funcione, saludos.